# App Permission declaration form rejected by Google

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-console

I recently received the notification from google that my app uses some of the permissions that are not necessary so I need to submit a declaration form  .So I submitted the declaration form .

They asked these questions so I replied this:-

## 1: In one sentence, please describe the core functionality of your app.

This is an security app, app uses sms in sense when there is not internet, app will send sms after asking user and giving full awarness about the sms sending, sms only will be send when user need not intensively, and will send to only user declear person whom user want to send

## 2: What is the core functionality in your app requiring the Call Log and / or SMS permissions?

Connected device companion apps that enable send and receive of SMS or calls `[SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS, READ_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, WRITE_CALL_LOG]`, N/A

## 4: Do any of the following other use cases apply to your app’s core functionality request for Call Log or SMS permissions?

Physical safety or emergency alerts.

After few Days I got this reply
We reviewed your request and found that your app does not qualify for use of the requested permissions for the following reasons:

The declared functionality `{CONNECTED_COMPANION_DEVICES}`  is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.
It looks like you are using SMS/Call Log permissions group for functions that might qualify for exceptions: `{SAFETY_EMERGENCY_ALERT}`.
Please declare it in the declaration and resubmit the form.

Please Tell me is there any solution to fix it ? What changes I need to make in my code?

Answer (score 1):

The first app that I developed and put on the playstore (very ugly) did exactly what yours does and so I received YOUR SAME NOTICE.
In fact, I am at the next step as I have started a "challenge" to request an exception.

They answered me like this:

**SMS / Call Log permissions group for ineligible functions: {Device Locator}**

.... but my app is a DEVICE LOCATOR! It's its main feature!Mahh

I suggest you do, as I did, by replying to the e-mail and saying if the localization apps are allowed or not via sms ... there is no written anywhere in the policies that is not allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am in a similar situation and they give no explanations so that we can make any claim. That's a totalitarian decision but they will say it's all for our own good.

Comment: In addition, in my case, app on the playstore compiled with API <23 for android 5, you can not even limit yourself to remove the permission SMS ... you must also program all the authorizations, management permissions, etc, a huge job on complex apps ... and only after doing this you can update the app ... as long as you do not invent anything else.

Comment: @Marios so did they allowed your app and havent removed it ? If yes so what exactly you said to them?

Comment: Absolutely not!
At the beginning I got this time (you had to apply with an online form) I think they granted it to everyone who requested it.
... I think I will remove the permissions and I will re-publish the non-working app, to take time and not to delete it from the playstore .... I think it's the only viable strategy.

Comment: I asked them again so I got this reply what i do next ?


I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that App does not qualify for use of SEND_SMS for the following reasons:

The declared functionality CONNECTED_COMPANION_DEVICES  is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.

It looks like you are using SMS/Call Log permissions group for functions that might qualify for exceptions: SAFETY_EMERGENCY_ALERT. Please declare it in the declaration and resubmit the form.

You need to ensure that your app no longer uses CONNECTED_COMPANION_DEVICEST;

Comment: I believe that the responder is a robot ... even if you declare SAFETY_EMERGENCY_ALERT in the form (which I did because my app does this) then they refuse you by saying that you have to find another way ... that is not there.

Comment: Ask Google everywhere to allow it . Raise Petition against it.

Comment: I've been asking everywhere and they don't reply, other than the lie that they determined my app doesn't do what I said despite providing video evidence, and they couldn't have possibly tested since they don't own the connected display in question